# FireMonkey: Missing Anti-Aliasing and jiggling effect on Android

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I created a progress animation with a TArc in Delphi 10.4 (FMX) but there are some weird rendering behaviours when running the app on Android.

1. None of the simple shapes, like TArc or TLine, seem to have Anti-Aliasing. Setting `TForm.Quality` to `HighQuality` seems to have no effect.
2. Setting `Arc1.Stroke.Cap := TStrokeCap.Round;` seems to have no effect on Android. The ends are not rounded at all.*
3. There seems to be some kind of jiggling problem with TFloatAnimation, but I cannot find out why.*

[image: Preview on Android and Windows]

*Everything looks and works good when running the app on Windows (10), but on Android there are these glitches and I would like to know, what the problem is. Especially with the missing Anti-Aliasing. Displays on smartphones are high-density, but the missing Anti-Aliasing is still very clearly visible. Here is a video captured from an Android device and from a desktop PC running Windows 10:

https://youtu.be/MyNva5ymSWU

Here's an example code:

**Unit1.fmx**

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 344
  ClientWidth = 427
  Fill.Color = claLightskyblue
  Fill.Kind = Solid
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object Arc1: TArc
    Align = Center
    Size.Width = 60.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 60.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Stroke.Color = claWhite
    Stroke.Thickness = 5.000000000000000000
    Stroke.Cap = Round
    EndAngle = 90.000000000000000000
    object FloatAnimationStartAngle: TFloatAnimation
      Enabled = True
      Duration = 2.000000000000000000
      Loop = True
      PropertyName = 'StartAngle'
      StartValue = 0.000000000000000000
      StopValue = 360.000000000000000000
    end
    object FloatAnimationEndAngle: TFloatAnimation
      Enabled = True
      Duration = 2.000000000000000000
      OnFinish = FloatAnimationEndAngleFinish
      PropertyName = 'EndAngle'
      StartValue = 1.000000000000000000
      StopValue = 360.000000000000000000
    end
  end
end
```

**Unit1.pas**

```
// ...stripped code here at top...
implementation

var
  increasing: Boolean = True;

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.FloatAnimationEndAngleFinish(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FloatAnimationEndAngle.Enabled := false;
  FloatAnimationEndAngle.Inverse := not FloatAnimationEndAngle.Inverse;

  if increasing then
    FloatAnimationEndAngle.Duration := FloatAnimationEndAngle.Duration * 2.0
  else
    FloatAnimationEndAngle.Duration := FloatAnimationEndAngle.Duration / 2.0;

  increasing := not increasing;
  FloatAnimationEndAngle.Enabled := true;
  FloatAnimationEndAngle.Start();
end;
```